# In-app-purchase, backend on php and iTunes response problem

Tags: php, iphone, in-app-purchase

Here is a sample PHP code for verifying the receipt:

```
public static function getReceiptData($receipt, $isSandbox = false) {
    if ($isSandbox)
        $endpoint = 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';
    else
        $endpoint = 'https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';
    $postData = "{\"receipt-data\":\"". base64_encode($receipt) ."\"}";
    $ch = curl_init($endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($errno != 0) {
        throw new sfException('connection_to_itunes_error', $errno);
    }
    // FIXME
    mail('my_mail', 'Invalid Itunes Receipt', var_export($data, true) . "\n" . $postData);
    $data = json_decode($response);
    if (!is_object($data)) {
        throw new sfException('invalid_response_data');

    if (!isset($data->status) || $data->status != 0) 
        throw new sfException('invalid_receipt');
    return $data;
}
```

So simple.

But I always get exception in response from iTunes:
I tried a lot of combinations of $postData string, but it doesn't help.

There are exceptions from the iTunes:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.webobjects.foundation.NSDictionary` for `{"receipt-data":"MTAwMDAwMDAwMTU1MjM1Ng=="}`

`java.lang.NullPointerException` for `"{"receipt-data":"MTAwMDAwMDAwMTU1MjM1Ng=="}"`

And so strange error
`'<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Your request produced an error.  <BR>[newNullResponse]</body></html>'` for string `"{\"receipt-data\":\"MTAwMDAwMDAwMTU1MjM1Ng==\"}"`

Could you provide the working json string for the recipt validation?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715414/apple-in-app-purchase-verify-receipt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your back-end looks like correct. Please, check iPhone code to send raw transaction receipt hex as string:

`NSString *receiptStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:transaction.transactionReceipt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

BTW, your script should also work without `base64_encode` for receipt string